# Generating Euler bricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I've been trying to create a python function that generates Euler Bricks.

I've tried to search online for topic on this problem, but it seems I can't figure it out. Any explanation about this math problem will be appreciated.

Comment: "I've been trying to do this exercise for my friend" -- is there any reason why your friend isn't doing their own homework?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm with you on this. But if he don't have the time to do it then that could be a reason. Maybe if you can give a hint or some explanation of the math here, it would be great

Comment: If you're fine with the programming part but not the math part, then this is a math question, not a programming question. Code is an implementation detail, the real important part is the actual design. We're not here to help you design your programs, we're here to help with specific code questions and issues. So you should ask the math questions on a site where it's allowed.

Comment: The cuboid function seems to be a simple check on whether or not 2 tuples of length 2 have a common element. It can easily be done in one line of code. Aftert that, for the brick function just compute the lengths of the diagonals (which is presumably what this unknown `Pyth` does), checking if they are integers. You probably aren't really helping your friend by doing their homework. How are they supposed to learn?

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for the brief explanation. He asked me for this. However, I agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for faces of a cuboid is trivial:

```
def CuboidFaces(s,t): return any(side in t for side in s)
```

To generate the bricks, you could use a naive "brute force" approach with nested loops on the 3 dimensions.  For each pair of dimension check that the diagonal of the corresponding rectangular face is an integer.  If all 3 pairs have integer diagonals, then you have a Euler brick.

```
def bricks(n):
    def intDiagonal(x,y):
        return (x*x+y*y)**0.5 % 1 == 0
    
    for a in range(1,n+1):
        for b in range(a+1,n+1):
            if not intDiagonal(a,b): continue
            for c in range(b+1,n+1):
                if intDiagonal(a,c) and intDiagonal(b,c):
                    print(a,b,c)
            
bricks(1000)

44 117 240
85 132 720
88 234 480
132 351 720
140 480 693
160 231 792
176 468 960
240 252 275
480 504 550
720 756 825
```

*To make this go faster, you can leverage the properties of a Euler brick.  For example, for the c loop, striding by a multiple of 11 and/or 3 and/or 4 depending on the values of a and b*

[EDIT] if you already have a function that gives you all the Pythagorean triples composed of numbers up to n, then you can make a dictionary out of the valid pairs and use it to form the bricks:

```
# list of pythagorean triples composed of numbers from 1 to n

def pythTriples(n):
    C2 = { c*c:c for c in range(1,n*3//2) }
    return [(A,B,C2[A*A+B*B]) for A in range(1,n) for B in range(A,n+1) if A*A+B*B in C2]

# Euler bricks are formed using a dictionary 
# giving a set of valid B for every A where A <= B
# (note that there are no conditional statements in the algorithm, 
#  the result is obtained directly from set intersections)

def eBricks(n):
    pythMap = {a:set() for a in range(1,n+1)}
    for a,b,_ in pythTriples(n):
        pythMap[a].add(b)

    for a in pythMap:
        for b in pythMap[a]:
            for c in pythMap[a] & pythMap[b]:
                yield (a,b,c)

for a,b,c in eBricks(1000): print (a,b,c)

44 117 240
85 132 720
88 234 480
132 351 720
140 480 693
160 231 792
176 468 960
240 252 275
480 504 550
720 756 825
```

[EDIT2] If you need to use CuboidFace() to brute force your way through valid faces (i.e. the ones produced by Pyth), you can match each valid (a,b) pair with all the other ones to find those that form a cuboid.  Then check that the third face is also valid to detect Euler bricks:

```
N = 1000
pythPairs  = [ (a,b) for a,b,_ in pythTriples(N) ] # valid faces
validFaces = set(pythPairs)                        # in a set to check faster 
for i,face1 in enumerate(pythPairs,1):             # for each valid face
    for face2 in pythPairs[i:]:                    # match with remaining faces
        if not CuboidFaces(face1,face2): continue     # must form a cuboid
        if face2[0] < face1[1]: continue              # avoid duplicates if needed
        face3 = tuple(sorted(set(face1)^set(face2)))  # form 3rd face
        if face3 in validFaces:                       # if 3rd face is valid
            print(face1,face2,face3, end=": ")        # then it's a Euler brick
            print(sorted({*face1,*face2}))            # print [a,b,c] form


(44, 117) (117, 240) (44, 240): [44, 117, 240]
(85, 132) (132, 720) (85, 720): [85, 132, 720]
(88, 234) (234, 480) (88, 480): [88, 234, 480]
(132, 351) (351, 720) (132, 720): [132, 351, 720]
(140, 480) (480, 693) (140, 693): [140, 480, 693]
(160, 231) (231, 792) (160, 792): [160, 231, 792]
(176, 468) (468, 960) (176, 960): [176, 468, 960]
(240, 252) (252, 275) (240, 275): [240, 252, 275]
(480, 504) (504, 550) (480, 550): [480, 504, 550]
(720, 756) (756, 825) (720, 825): [720, 756, 825]
```

Comment: Probably adequate for this purpose, but `intDiagonal` as written will sooner or later fail because of round-off error.

Comment: Agreed.  I just wanted to illustrate the approach with simple code.  Optimization and edge cases were beyond my intent.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This really help to get some idea about Euler brick. However, I want to read more about the topic as I want to do it in a more efficient way using CuboidFaces and Pyth (which generate Pythagorean triples)

Comment: Having to use CuboidFaces means you're going to generate faces in a trial and error process where the function will serve as a filter for the invalid combinations.  If you already have your valid Pythagorean triples, you can generate valid bricks directly with a simple set intersection process (see my EDIT)

Comment: Hi Alain, Thank you for the great help!

Comment: Some combinations of **a** and **b** will have no matching **c** value.  That's normal and expected.  If you're never getting any **c** in that loop, you probably didn't copy the code precisely (I just pasted it again in IDLE and it gives the correct result). BTW the function is a generator, it does not return an array. It is meant to be used in a for loop or comprehension.  To get a list you can do `list(eBricks(1000))`

Comment: Hi Alain, the output of eBricks() seems to be wrong. It starts with 5 12 16

Comment: I added the results that i'm getting (Python 3.7)

Comment: Yea, I've tried now and it worked, Thank you. However, if I want to use the CuboidFaces, can I add it as a condition after the first for loop?

Comment: You could add `if CuboidFaces((a,b),(b,c)):` inside the `for c in ...` loop but that would be kind of weird given that it will always return True.

Comment: In the exercise, they require to use CuboidFaces function, so I'm thinking how I could use it

Comment: Thank you so much bro. I don't want to take more time from you. The example was great

Comment: They probably want you to create a list of valid (a,b) pairs/faces from the Pyth function and then try every pair with every other pair (trial and error) checking with CuboidFace.  The pairs/faces that match with CuboidFace will be Euler bricks if the non-matching side is also in the list of (a,b) Pyth pairs.

Comment: I've create a Pyth function that creates a list of (x,y,z) triples. Do you mean that I should check x and y? or I should create the Pyth function in a different way

Comment: I've created a list of valid (a,b) pairs/faces but what do mean to check with every other pair?

Comment: See my EDIT2 for an illustration of what I meant.